# Apache Hive: CREATE TABLE statement without schema over parquet can fail to infer partition column

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hiveql

I have a partitioned parquet at the following path:

`/path/to/partitioned/parq/`

with partitions like:

```
/path/to/partitioned/parq/part_date=2021_01_01_01_01_01
/path/to/partitioned/parq/part_date=2021_01_02_01_01_01
/path/to/partitioned/parq/part_date=2021_01_03_01_01_01
```

When I run a Spark SQL CREATE TABLE statement like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
my_db.my_table
USING PARQUET 
LOCATION '/path/to/partitioned/parq'
```

The partition column `part_date` shows up in my dataset, but DESCRIBE EXTENDED indicates there are no PARTITIONS. `SHOW PARTITIONS my_db.my_table` shows no partition data.

This seems to happen intermittently, like sometimes spark infers the partitions, other times it doesn't. This is causing issues downstream where we add a partition and try to `MSCK REPAIR TABLE my_db.my_table` and it says you can't run that on non-partitioned tables.

I see that if you DO declare schema, you can FORCE the `PARTITIONED BY` part of the clause but we do not have the luxury of a schema, just the files from underneath.

Why is spark intermittently unable to determine partition columns from a parquet in this shape?

Comment: Did u find otherwise?

Comment: So you can answer your question now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Unfortunately with Hive you need to specify the schema, even if parquet obviously has this itself.
- You need to add partition by clause to DDL.
- Use ALTER table statement to add each partition separately with location.

Comment: You do NOT need to specify schema with hive. it will infer it (albeit intermittently incorrectly)  apparently if you do not provide it. This is a valid hive CREATE statement: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_db.my_table USING PARQUET LOCATION '/path/to/partitioned/parq'`

Comment: Incorrect means…

Comment: incorrect means sometimes it will not add the partition information to the DESCRIBE EXTENDED output. It always does when explicitly declared of course.

Comment: We parsed the schema from the parquet, converted it to a SQL statement with partition by, and that solved the problem